# How to preprocess with categorical data and dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am preprocessing data for my multiple linear regression model by having a list of genres which I onehotencode

```
genres = [
    "Action",
    "Adventure",
    "Biography",
    "Comedy",
    "Crime",
    "Erotica",
    "Fantasy",
    "Historical fiction",
    "Horror",
    "Mystery",
    "Romance",
    "Satire",
    "Scifi",
    "Speculative",
    "Thriller",
    "Western",
]
```

And I also have a user input `x_user`

```
x_user = ["Action", "Thriller",]
```

I want to use `x_user` as my `X_new` in:

```
clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X, Y)
clf.predict([X_new])
```

As I understand it I have to use numeric values when using prediction, so I need to convert x_user to an array X_new with bool as `[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]`

Is this possible to do with pandas?

I tried

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=genres, columns=["genres"])
df['X_new'] = df.genres.apply(lambda q: q.intercept(x_user)).astype(bool)
```

But got an error

What's the correct way of doing this?

**EDIT**

My training set looks something like this (after onehotencode)

| Y | Action | Adventure | ... | Thriller | Western |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.2 | 1 | 0 | ... | 1 | 1 |
| 4.7 | 0 | 1 | ... | 1 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

And the test set is from a user input and looks something like (after onehotencode)

| Action | Thriller |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

But I want it to look like this

| Action | Adventure | ... | Thriller | Western |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | ... | 1 | 0 |

Comment: Please explain your question in more details.

Comment: Added edit to my post

Answer (score 0):

Could it be something as simple as:

```
X_new = pd.DataFrame(0, index=np.arange(len(x_user)), columns=genres)
X_new['Action'] = x_user.Action
X_new['Thriller'] = x_user.Thriller
```

assuming x_user is a pandas dataframe. If it is instead a numpy array or something similar just assign it based on its index.

If you manage the columns of x_user so that they are in the correct order you could generalise to:

```
X_new[['Action','Thriller']] = x_user
```

If x_user is a pandas dataframe:

```
X_new[X_user.columns] = x_user.values
```

Comment: Maybe, it looks promising. But how do I generalize the solution. Let's say the user input changes to different genres?

Comment: I made some changes. Let me know if thats what you need.